# Storing Tree Data Structures

Tags: vb.net, data-structures, tree

I have a trinomial tree structure built in vb.net.
Each node is created as an Object with certain properties.
These nodes are stored in an ArrayList.
These ArrayLists are then stored in another ArrayList which would be the tree.

When I run this on say, 4000 steps (i.e. 4000 ArrayLists in my tree), the final ArrayList will have 8001 nodes. The total number of objects is approximately 8000*4000/3 = approx > 10 million nodes.

This is causing the program to crash due to memory overflow.

What is the best method for storing my tree such that it could be made as large as I would like? Is a database or text file the way forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to compress the tree as follows:

Map each Object to a unique id and then store only the ids in the ArrayLists. The specific properties of each Object could be stored in a database. And you could query the database whenever you need to access the properties of a specific Object.

If there are frequently access Object instances, you could also use some sort of caching scheme to store the properties of those Objects in memory.

**EDIT:** If the ArrayLists of ids also start exceeding the memory, then you could try assigning ids to ArrayLists as well and store the contents of these ArrayLists in the database.

To summarize, use some sort of compression mechanism (to reduce  memory consumption) and couple this with a good caching mechanism (to reduce the number of disk accesses).